# Slow loading rails environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, environment

Is it OK that loading my rails environment takes 25 seconds?

```
alhafoudh@xxx:~/Projects/xxx$ time ruby -r./config/environment.rb -e ""
real    0m25.320s
user    0m22.093s
sys     0m1.988s

alhafoudh@xxx:~/Projects/xxx$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18 revision 29036) [i686-linux]

alhafoudh@xxx:~/Projects/xxx$ gem list | grep rails
using rails 3.0.3
```

I am using also rvm

Comment: With ruby 1.8.7 (2010-04-19 patchlevel 253) [i686-linux], MBARI 0x8770, Ruby Enterprise Edition 2010.02 it takes 10 seconds, can someone explain it to me?

Comment: It took 16 seconds for me the first time I tried, then only 4.

Comment: What PC platform and ruby stack are you using?

Comment: To answer this we'll need a lot more information about your configuration and app setup. Rails takes about 5 seconds on my MacBook Pro in a production config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it with downgrating my ruby stack to ree-1.8.7 :(

Answer (score 1):

Bundler 1.1 helps speed things up, somewhat (20-25% gains).

Otherwise, remove unnecessary gems, if any - and harp on gem authors to lazy-load their library to speed things up.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: switching recommendation per comment suggestion

No need to downgrade. One workaround for this is to preload the rails environment with [rails-sh](https://github.com/jugyo/rails-sh). That way only the first rails/rake command is slow and the rest are pretty fast.  Wrote a fuller answer to it in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11479744/462002). I use it currently with ruby 1.9.3p194 with rails 3.2.6.

Comment: rrails looks fine, rails server starts very fast, but rails console does not work (hangs) and rake spec tells me "uninitialized constant FactoryGirl" There is no documentation for rrails. :(

Comment: I [inquired](https://github.com/walf443/rrails/issues/2) from the rrails project about that.  Seems rrails wasn't built for console REPLs.  He suggested trying the similar [rails-sh](https://github.com/jugyo/rails-sh)

Comment: Yep, after trying it out, it seems rails-sh is a better fit due to it's REPL support.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use sqlite or other client-server database engine?

Please run rails console and check whether calling reload! method is also slow...

Comment: It does approx. the same times with sqlite, mysql or mysql2 gem. Reload! Is within a second.

As I wrote, I tried it with ree-1.8.7 and takes 7-10 seconds.